# Spring Security : How to Authorize functions without log in

Tags: spring-security

I implemented spring security in my web application. Now all my services are secured and can be only invoked by authorised users. Everything works on webside, but when I call function without log in doesn't work.

here is my **Controller(RestController)**

```
@RestController

public class MessageService {

    @Autowired
    MessageModel messageModel;

    @RequestMapping(value="/message",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public Message save(@RequestBody Message message) {
        return messageModel.save(message);
    }

    @PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
    @RequestMapping(value="/messagee",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public Message savee(@RequestBody Message message) {
        System.out.println("hjgjhghggfhgf");
        return messageModel.savee(message);
    }
}
```

I am using **angularjs** client side.

Answer (score 0):

The functions are not supposed to work as they are secured by spring security. To allow a few functions to be accessed anonymously, you need to configure spring security to do so.
Depending on what configuration you are using, I would suggest the below:
If you are using XML/Java route based config, I would recommend you to do something like this:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/trusted/**" filters="none" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
```

If you are using the @PreAuthorize annotation, I would recommend you to do something like this:

```
@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
public void YourAnonymousController(){
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

EDIT 1: Please note that you remove the route based security config. Try adding @PreAuthorize("hasRole()") on functions you want to keep secured and @PreAuthorize("permitAll()") on anonymous functions.

Comment: thanks, i try it but it doesn't work, i edit the description of problem , if you have any ideas

Comment: Check the edited reply. You need to remove <security:intercept-url pattern="/trusted/**" filters="none" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" /> or any java based route config. I guess it should work after that